# Why I can't use `let` in this example?

Tags: let-binding, parentheses

I am learning Emacs lisp and wrote a function which takes as input a list of file name, and
returns a list of numbers of each defun in a file (introduced in [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/lengths_002dlist_002dfile.html#lengths_002dlist_002dfile) tutorial)

```
(lengths-list-file "/usr/share/emacs/28.0.50/lisp/simpl.el")
=> (49, 49, 49, ... )
```

I tried to write another function, which takes a list of filenames and return an `append`-ed
list of return values of `lengths-list-file` of each element in the list.

```lisp
(defun lengths-list-files2 (list-of-files)
  "Return list of lengths of defuns in LIST-OF-FILES."

  (let (lengths-list)
    (dolist (filename list-of-files lengths-list)
      (let (cur-lengths-list
            (lengths-list-file filename))
        (message "%d" (length cur-lengths-list))
        (setq lengths-list
              (append lengths-list
                      cur-lengths-list))))
    lengths-list))
```

Here I first used `let` to bind `(lengths-list-file filename)` to a symbol `cur-length-list`, however, I found out that `cur-lengths-list` was always `nil`.

Instead, I removed `let` expression, and I found that it started to work as I expected:

```lisp
(defun lengths-list-files (list-of-files)
  "Return list of lengths of defuns in LIST-OF-FILES."

  (let (lengths-list)
    (dolist (filename list-of-files lengths-list)
      (setq lengths-list
            (append lengths-list
                    (lengths-list-file filename))))
    lengths-list))
```

What is the reason that the function with `let` within the `dolist` block failed to produce correct result? (i.e., why `cur-lengths-list` is always `nil`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```el
      (let (cur-lengths-list
            (lengths-list-file filename))
```

> Here I first used `let` to bind `(lengths-list-file filename)` to a symbol `cur-lengths-list`

No, you bound `cur-lengths-list` to `nil` (hence "I found out that cur-lengths-list was always nil"), and then you bound `lengths-list-file` to the value of the variable `filename`.

You wanted this:

```el
      (let ((cur-lengths-list
             (lengths-list-file filename)))
```

See `C-h f let` for details.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to wrap it with another pair of parentheses. Thanks